# I can't write in my DB using $wpdb->insert

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, sql

Building a plugin I'm trying to insert something in my DB but isn't works!

My code is like that:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."mytable"; 
$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'name'=>"'".$_POST["name"]."'"
    ),
    array(
        '%s'
    )
);
```

I have a string in my $_POST["name"] and my database only have 2 columns: id, who is AUTO_INCREMENT and Name.

I don't know if I need do something more than the $wpdb->insert('xxxxxxx') but: Wordpress don't send me any error in PHP or SQL and don't insert anything in my database.

Comment: [Enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: I bet it has to do with the type of `name` col That if the table is there. BTW you should sanitize, escape and validate as you insert to the DB. https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/vip/best-practices/security/validating-sanitizing-escaping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the problem is first array. Change it to

```
array(
    'name' => $_POST['name']
),
```

You can also use [wpdb->show_error() or wpdb->print_error()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors)

To Samuel Elh: wpdb->insert() can [escape value itself](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database)

Comment: I'm looking for that error...thanks! I didn't see! Now works well